# Ubuntu Snappy OVA image cannot login

Tags: login, vmware, ubuntu-core

I'm trying the OVA image with VMWare workstation, I've made the user-data & meta-data:

user-data:

```
cat >> user-data << EOF
#cloud-config
snappy: 
    ssh_enabled: true
password: passw0rd
chpasswd: { expire: False }
ssh_pwauth: True
EOF
```

meta-data:

```
cat >> meta-data << EOF
instance-id: $(uuidgen)
local-hostname: ubuntu-snappy
EOF
```

I have generated the seed.iso, mounted it as a CD-ROM on the VM and snappy boots up alright. The trouble is I cannot log in. I've tried "ubuntu" and the password set by the meta-data but it just says login incorrect.

I've tried modifying the `#cloud-config` but still cannot login. One thing i noticed, which I believe is an error, is that Ubuntu documented that to generate the user-data, you had to put in

```
cat >> meta-data <<"EOF`
```

which gives me an error because of the `"`.

Likewise for the `chpasswd`, they forgot to close the `{`.

Has anyone succeeded with the OVA image and if so, what could be a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue. I noticed the errors on the documentation as well. Here is how I finally resolved the issue. Note ssh_enabled boolean is capitalized to conform to the rest of the booleans. Also, note that I did not use the bloat file when generating the image as I did not need to use the vmdk. Lastly, before attempting this new image, delete your previous virtual machine import as that import is altered every time you start the machine with a cloud init file. If you use these notes, the login should be

> ubuntu

and the password should be

> passw0rd

.

```
$ cat >> user-data << EOF
#cloud-config
snappy: 
    ssh_enabled: True
password: passw0rd
chpasswd: { expire: False }
ssh_pwauth: True
EOF

$ cat >> meta-data << EOF
instance-id: $(uuidgen)
local-hostname: ubuntu-snappy
EOF

$ genisoimage \
    -output seed.iso \
    -volid cidata \
    -joliet -rock \
     user-data meta-data
```